# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib

Tags: xcode, dylib, carthage, rpath

After the update of Carthage to 0.18 (via homebrew), call of the carthage become broken:

```
$ carthage
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/ReactiveCocoa.framework/ReactiveCocoa
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I tried to reinstall or to clean and update manually. Both variants didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved by remove `/Library/Frameworks/ReactiveCocoa.framework` which was placed manually sometimes ago.

`@rpath` contains multiple locations and after finding that `ReactiveCocoa` is at `/Library/Frameworks/` linker stops there. After removal it finds another location of ReactiveCocoa which also contains required dependencies.